# Image array for classification in sklearn pipeline - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a images that I want to classify as either A or B. To do that, I load and resize them to size 160x160 and then convert the 2D-Array to 1D and add them to a pandas dataframe:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
rows = []
for product in products:
    try:
        relevant = product.categoryrelevant.all()[0].relevant
    except IndexError:
        relevant = False
    if relevant:
        relevant = "A"
    else:
        relevant = "B"
    # this exists for all pictures
    image_array = imread("{}/{}".format(MEDIA_ROOT, product.picture_file.url))
    image_array = imresize(image_array, (160, 160))
    image_array = image_array.reshape(-1)
    print(image_array)
    # [254 254 252 ..., 255 255 253]
    print(image_array.shape)
    # (76800,)
    rows.append({"id": product.pk, "image": image_array, "class": relevant})
    index.append(product)
df = DataFrame(rows, index=index)
```

I want to have more than just the image used for classification later (as an example, a product description) so I am using a Pipeline with FeatureUnion (even though it has only the image for now). ItemSelector is taken from here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html

It takes the values in the "image" column. Alternatively ìt would be possible to do `train_X = df.iloc[train_indices]["image"].values`, but I want to add other columns later.

```
def randomforest_image_pipeline():
    """Returns a RandomForest pipeline."""
    return Pipeline([
        ("union", FeatureUnion(
            transformer_list=[
                ("image", Pipeline([
                    ("selector", ItemSelector(key="image")),
                ]))
            ],
            transformer_weights={
                "image": 1.0
            },
        )),
        ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier()),
    ])
```

And then classify with KFold:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold(tested_pipeline=randomforest_image_pipeline(), df=df)
def kfold(tested_pipeline=None, df=None, splits=6):
    k_fold = KFold(n_splits=splits)
    for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold.split(df):
        # training set
        train_X = df.iloc[train_indices]
        train_y = df.iloc[train_indices]['class'].values
        # test set
        test_X = df.iloc[test_indices]
        test_y = df.iloc[test_indices]['class'].values
        for val in train_X["image"]:
            print(len(val), val.dtype, val.shape)
            # 76800 uint8 (76800,) for all
        tested_pipeline.fit(train_X, train_y) # crashes in this call
        pipeline_predictions = tested_pipeline.predict(test_X)
        ...
```

However for `.fit` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/project/classifier/classify.py", line 362, in <module>
    best = best_pipeline(dataframe=data, f1_scores=f1_dict, get_fp=True)
  File "<path>/project/classifier/classify.py", line 351, in best_pipeline
    confusion_list=confusion_list, get_fp=get_fp)
  File "<path>/project/classifier/classify.py", line 65, in kfold
    tested_pipeline.fit(train_X, train_y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 270, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py", line 247, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I found other people with the same problem and for them the problem was that their rows were not the same length. This does not seem to be the case for me, as all of the rows are 1-dimensional with length 76800:

```
    for val in train_X["image"]:
        print(len(val), val.dtype, val.shape)
        # 76800 uint8 (76800,) for all
```

`array` in the line where it crashes looks like this (copied from the debugger):

```
[array([ 255.,  255.,  255., ...,  255.,  255.,  255.])
 array([ 255.,  255.,  255., ...,  255.,  255.,  255.])
 array([ 255.,  255.,  255., ...,  255.,  255.,  255.]) ...,
 array([ 255.,  255.,  255., ...,  255.,  255.,  255.])
 array([ 255.,  255.,  255.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are saving all the data of your image i.e 76800 features in a list and that list is saved into a single column of the dataFrame.

So when you use the ItemSelector to choose that column, the output from that will be a single dimension array of shape `(Train_len, )`. The internal dimension of 76800 is not visible to the FeatureUnion or subsequent estimator.

Change the `transform()` function of ItemSelector to return a proper 2-d data array with shape (Train_len, 76800). Only then it will work.

Change to:

```
def transform(self, data_dict):
    return np.array([np.array(x) for x in data_dict[self.key]])
```

Feel free to ask if not understand anything.

Comment: @Lomtrur Great! Now make sure that the other transformers you add in the FeatureUnion, also return a 2-d array. Only then they will be combined correctly.